# How to re-use an sqlx::Executor?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm trying to develop an app server in Rust using SQLX for back-end storage.  It's for a primitive CMS with some idiosyncratic default behavior, to wit: if the page is not found, generate it automatically with some blank content.  I want to be able to re-use the functions that invoke the SQL, so I want them to take types implementing the `sqlx::Executor` trait, including `&mut sqlx::Connection`, `&mut sqlx::pool::PoolConnection`, and `&mut sqlx::Transaction`.

Every function with a *single* call to the database works great!

*However*, it seems like I can't re-use an executor. This function is called after I've determined the page does not exist; I create a transaction and call it with an `&mut Transaction` as the `e` argument:

```
async fn create_page_for_title(e: impl Executor<'_, Database = Sqlite>, title: &str) -> SqlResult<RawPage> {
    let newcontent_id = insert_new_root_content(e).await?;
    let newpage = insert_new_page(e, title, newcontent_id).await?;
    Ok(newpage)
}
```

And this is what Rust (1.46) says:

```
Error[E0382]: use of moved value: `e`
   --> src/store.rs:239:30
    |
230 | async fn create_page_for_title(e: impl Executor<'_, Database = Sqlite>, title: &str) -> SqlResult<RawPage>
    |                                - move occurs because `e` has type `impl Executor<'_, Database = Sqlite>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
238 |     let newcontent_id = insert_new_root_content(e).await?;
    |                                                 - value moved here
239 |     let newpage = insert_new_page(e, title, newcontent_id).await?;
    |                                   ^ value used here after move
```

I know `e` is a reference, and references are `Copy`. But I seem to be unable to convince Rust of this, and I'm not sure why. This is the only function where I use an `impl Executor` twice in the same scope, but I'm sure I'll discover more as time goes on. Please help?

Comment: Would the `Acquire` trait work? It lets you begin a transaction to receive a concrete `Transaction` object, which you can then use to execute multiple queries.

Comment: Also, only immutable references are `Copy`. If you're OK with this restriction you can add a bound to your signature, such that `e: impl Executor<...> + Copy`.

Comment: @apetranzilla That's the insight I was missing, that it has to be immutable. Thanks. By streamlining the function calls for generating the content object, the unique slug (not shown here), and then the page object, I was able to craft a function that wasn't nearly as ugly, using the `&mut tx` object in the caller.

Comment: Can you post your resulting code please? I am wondering what is the answer here.

Comment: Any news in v0.6.0